# Android : WorkManager Update Repeat Interval Runtime

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have created WorkRequest on WorkManager. I just used first time.

I am stuck to update Repeat Interval when server sends me new interval.

Is this possible to update WorkRequest's Interval runtime when its changed on server side.

I have tried as follow:

My code is:

```
public static void startLocationTracker() {
        /**
         * Getting Default Minutes from General Params
         */
        List<GeneralParamMaster> generalParamMasters = CommonUses.getGeneralSettings();
        int repeatInterval = 0;
        if (generalParamMasters.size() > 0) {
            repeatInterval = TextUtils.isEmpty(generalParamMasters.get(0).getAutoLatLongTime()) ? DEFAULT_LOCATION_UPDATE_TIME : Integer.parseInt(generalParamMasters.get(0).getAutoLatLongTime());
        }
        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, repeatInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag("Location")
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Location", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, periodicWork);
}
```

**My Question/Confusion is::**

- What if I call same function with as above?
- Is there any method to update interval run time?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because you're enqueueing a new `WorkRequest` as a Unique periodic work,  replacing whatever was the previour `WorkRequest` and its Interval.

Keep in mind that it may happens that you replace a PeriodWorker while it is running, because you're using `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE`. If another worker, associated to the same `UniqueName`, it's running while you call `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork`, the Worker will be cancelled and the new one will be scheduled.

For this reason it's important to handle the cancellation correctly in your `Worker` class, as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work).

Comment: I'm doing the same once I got my API result in doWork(), but for me, doWork() is calling again. So it going to loop.

Comment: Why are you enqueuing a unique periodic work from your worker? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my aim is to update the time interval for already enqueued UniquePeriodicWork. Here is my code sample.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298931/how-to-update-timeinterval-for-periodicworkrequest-after-dowork-call

Comment: Ok, I've answered on that question.

Answer (score 0):

1. pfmaggi already answered this above; if you call this method a second time, it will replace your original WorkRequest.
2. You can update your interval by calling the same method that you have and use ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE with a different length of time.

Answer (score 0):

I posted solution to similar queston [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083178/5161373).

The point is to keep your interval in sharedPrefs, and check if it is changed, and based on that condition, to use KEEP or REPLACE policy.