# How to update timeInterval for PeriodicWorkRequest after doWork() call

Tags: android, android-service, androidx, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm new to Work manager in android and I want to update the timeInterval of PeriodicWorkRequest once I got the response from server. Here is my sample code where I'm trying to update the timeInterval. But it is going to an infinite loop of calling the doWork() function. Please suggest to me where it is wrong.

```
class RandomNumberGenerator(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(
context,
workerParams) {

private val min = 0
private val max = 100
var randomNumber = 0
var context: Context

init {
    Log.d(TAG, "Constructor invoked")
    this.context = context
    Log.d(TAG, "" + workerParams.id.toString())
}

private fun startRandomNumberGenerator() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startRandomNumberGenerator: isStopped: $isStopped")
    var i = 0
    while (i < 5) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            randomNumber = Random().nextInt(max) + min
            Log.d(
                TAG,
                "Thread Id: " + Thread.currentThread().id + " Random Number: " + randomNumber
            )
            i++
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }

        if (i == 5) {
            callUpdateSyncTime()
        }
    }

}

private fun callUpdateSyncTime() {
    Log.d(TAG, "callUpdateSyncTime() called")

    val periodicWork =
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(RandomNumberGenerator::class.java, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "work_manager_random",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            periodicWork
        )
}

companion object {
    const val TAG = "WorkManager"
}

override fun doWork(): Result {
    startRandomNumberGenerator()
    return Result.success()
}

override fun onStopped() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStopped() called")
    super.onStopped()
}
```

}

Here is the code how I'm enqueuing from my MainActivity

```
val workRequestRandomNumber: PeriodicWorkRequest =
        PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RandomNumberGenerator>(
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES
        ).build()
    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        "work_manager_random",
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        workRequestRandomNumber
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enqueue a PeriodicWorkRequest, it will be executed immeditially if you don't add an initial delay using [`setInitialDelay()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#setInitialDelay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Given that you are rescheduling your worker each time it's completed, I would suggest to use a `OneTimeWorkRequest`, instead of a repeating one, with an initial delay:

```kotlin
val workRequestRandomNumber =
        OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RandomNumberGenerator>()
            .setInitialDelay(
                15,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("work_manager_random")
            .build()

workManager.enqueue(workRequestRandomNumber)
```

As it is right now, WorkManager is sending a cancellation to your worker that you are ignoring.